# How to change WooCommerce product title on loop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woothemes, woocommerce-theming

how to change WooCommerce product title on loop, for example change product tile in `shop, category` page etc.?

I am looking for the hook that can help to solve this issue. When going to `woocommerce/content-product.php` it is showing

```php
do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title');

echo '<div class="title-wrapper">';
do_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title');
echo '</div>';
```

please help

I want to change the product tile on `shop page, category page` etc.. But in `single product page, or cart, checkout` page I don't want to change title. Also what about shortcodes `[products ids="12,34,56,"];`?
How can I change the title?

Comment: Hi, What title you want to give?

Comment: (`product tile`→ *product title*?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
remove_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title',10);
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','fun',10);
function fun()
{
   echo 'Your Title for the product';
}
```

The above code will remove the **Default Title** and call another function which will show your own title in place. Now you have write your own logic for each product title. I tested with it, and it works for me.

Hope it works for you too.

Comment: Do you need the ajax loading into your other questions or the page loading time is the main concern

Comment: First i will show category 1 and it's 4 products . When user scroll down the page then the next 4 products from category 1 should load . this will continue until all product from category 1 loaded . Afte this Category 2 title will show . Then 4 products from category 2 should load ,When user scroll down the page then the next 4 products from category 2 should  be load like this .