# How can I add a title to the Woocommerce product title links?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to truncate my Woocommerce product titles with text-overflow:ellipsis, but for better usability I also want to add a title to the product title links so that users can hover over and see the full title. How can I add titles to the product title links? I need

```
<a href="..." title="Product title">Product title</a>
```

Comment: Do you mean for the links on your shop page / archive pages?

Comment: for archive product pages - $product->get_name();

Comment: Have a read of this possible solution- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47862563/how-to-change-woocommerce-product-title-on-loop

Comment: @Terminator-Barbapapa Yes, for shop/archive pages.